# AWS cloudformation waitcondtion for VPN gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create VPN gateway and route table entry which need VPN gateway as dependency. Due to race condition, route table entry (i.e. RouteA), is unable to find the VPN gateway by the time of its creation. I tried adding WaitCondition to solve this issue, but it needs a success condition. Looking at AWS documentation, I couldn't find any way to send success signal after creation of VPN gateway. Here is the code:

```
"VPNGateway" : {
     "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPNGateway",
     "Properties" : {
       "Type" : "ipsec.1"
     }
   },
   "WaitHandle" : {
     "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle"
   },        
   "WaitCondition" : {
     "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition",
     "DependsOn" : "VPNGateway",
     "Properties" : {
       "Handle"  : { "Ref" : "WaitHandle" },
       "Timeout" : "300"
     }
   },
   "RouteA": {
     "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
     "DependsOn": ["VPNGateway"],
     "Properties": {
       "DestinationCidrBlock": {"Ref": "CidrBlock"},
       "RouteTableId": {"Ref": "PrivateRouteTableA"},
       "GatewayId": {"Ref": "VPNGateway"}
     }
   }
```

Comment: Adding `DependsOn` to `RouteA` didn't wait for the `VPNGateway` to finish?

Comment: DependsOn controls the order in which your CloudFormation resources are created, i.e., creation of a specific resource follows another. DependsOn doesn’t wait for success or failure signals from AWS resources before moving forward. Source: https://cloudacademy.com/blog/working-with-waitcondition-on-awss-cloudformation/

Comment: Your DependsOn will wait until the VPNGateway is CREATED.  (I didn't read the link, but I know it will wait until it is CREATED).  Is the issue that the VPNGateway is not started or fully initialized?

Comment: VPNGateway was created but not fully initialised. I had created a nested stacks to add route entries.